# How to enter a list into a function? in python

Tags: python

Write a function called “find_even_count” which allows the user to enter an arbitrary sequence of positive integers at the keyboard, and then prints the number of positive even integers user enters. The sequence of numbers is unknown at the beginning. User may enter negative number to show the end of the sequence.
For example: If user enters the sequence,
1, 3, 5, 23, 56, 14, 68, 25, 12, -1
then your function needs to print “4 even numbers”, since there are 4 even numbers in the sequence.
Hint: Use while loop

here is my code

```
find_even_count(x):
    i = x
    even_count = 0
    while x> 0:
            if i%2 ==0:
                    even_count+=1

    print even_count
```

I keep getting the error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    find_even_count(2,22,224,24,-1)
  File "/Users/rayhow/Desktop/assignment2_Q4.py", line 5, in find_even_count
    if i%2 ==0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Comment: Are you missing `def` in your code or did it get cutoff while copying?

Comment: it must of got cut off

Comment: also i am suppose to list a group of integers and have a count of the even number and have the script end when i enter a negative integer

Comment: Is this some kind of homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go my friend

```
input_list = raw_input('give me list of numbers: ')
print(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() and not int(x) % 2, input_list.split()))
```

will give you

```
(ocmg)brunsgaard@archbook /tmp> python pos.py
give me list of numbers: 1 2 3 4 -2 -1 your mother 54
['2', '4', '54']
```

Also if you want a more simple solution go with

```
even = lambda l: len([x for x in l if not x % 2 and x > 0])
```

This will output

```
even([1, -2, 3, 4, 6, 5])
2
```

Because there are 2 even numbers

Comment: i haven't gone over any of those commands yet just basic while and for loops.

Comment: @Ray-RayHow, fine :) Just go with the answers you find most comfortable.. This solution is a little advanced, but in my opnion also be the best one yet ;)

Comment: @Ray-RayHow, I improved my answer to give you another solution

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_even_count(x):
    even_count = 0
    for n in x:
            if n%2 ==0:
                    even_count+=1

    print even_count
```

Comment: This would fail the homework test, because it doesn't let the user enter numbers.   The question does not ask for a solution to the homework assignment in any case, it asks for help with an error message.