# Python Find Even Count

Tags: python, loops

> Write a function called “ find_even_count ” which allows the user to enter an arbitrary sequence of positive integers at the keyboard, and then prints the number of positive even integers user enters . User may enter negative number to show the end of the sequence.

Here is the code I have so far for this:

```
def find_even_count(n):
    x = 0
    even_count = 0
    for n in xrange(x):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
    print even_count


>>> find_even_count(4)
0
```

I am having a couple problems

1. As you see the output is 0 even when an even number is present
2. I cant write more than 1 number as my input.

Comment: xrange(x) is always empty, because x is zero.

Comment: so i should change it to xrange(1, n-1) ?

Comment: This may be a helpful tool as you learn:  http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394666/how-to-enter-a-list-into-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking at the numbers from 0 to 0.

```
x = 0
even_count = 0
for n in xrange(x):
```

I think you mean `for num in xrange(n)`.

But if you want to input a list of numbers, which I think you do since you say the user should enter an arbitrary sequence of numbers, then you would just have:

`for num in n`

Comment: This is missing the point, because the problem is "user enters arbitrary sequence of numbers", `xrange` shouldn't appear in the answer at all.

Comment: Then how do I write it omitting that part?

Comment: You can iterate over a list with `for item in list`.  Edited

Comment: Then you would call the function by find_even_count([1,2,3])

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `xrange` to generate numbers, you should be checking the numbers from a given list (based on the problem statement)

```
def find_even_count(n):
    even_count = 0
    for num in n:
        if num%2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
    return even_count

>>> find_even_count([1,2,4,6,9,8])
4
```

Note the above method is an attempt to follow the flow of your current function. A more concise and pythonic method would be to use a list comprehension to filter out the even numbers, then use `len` to determine how many numbers were kept

```
def find_even_count(n):
    return len([i for i in n if i%2==0])

>>> find_even_count([1,2,4,6,9,8])
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's work with problem #1.

You are seeing a `0` returned because your `for n in xrange(x)` call will not result in any iteration and the function will print `even_count` which is set to `0` and return!

You need to fix this by doing this:

```
for x in range(n):
    if x %2 == 0:
        even_count += 1
```

For problem #2, you have to pass your function a list rather than a single value. I am not sure why you call xrange() in the function you have since you want to work with user-entered sequence rather than a sequence you generate!

```
def find_even_count(seq):
    even_count = 0
    for num in seq:
         if num%2 == 0:
              even_count += 1
    return even_count
```

This function can also be called to do what your previous function did like this:

```
print find_even_count(xrange(4))
```

Now that you have a function which counts even numbers in a sequence, you have to accept user input, using `input` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different parts to this problem.  The first part is gathering information.  The second is interpreting it.

I would recommend breaking this up into 2 different stages.

First write a function that takes numbers from input until a negative number is entered and just returns the number of numbers entered.

Then tackle the problem as written.

If you need more help, I can edit this answer with additional hints/code.  But because this is a homework problem, I think it would be helpful if you worked it out more or less by yourself.

At the end of the day iterating through a list is superfluous because you can do that in your input loop anyway.  So don't concentrate on figuring out that part first.  Concentrate on the input part of the problem.

Hint #1

> The way to grab an integer input from the user is by using `variable = int(input("Enter your number: "))`  See: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html

Hint #2

> Because you need to do this indefinitely, you need to have a loop that can run infinitely.  The easiest way to do this is `while (1):` and using `break` when the loop should terminate.

Solution

> `def find_even_count():
>    total = 0
>    while (1):
>      num = int(input("Enter a number, use negative numbers to stop the program: "))
>      if (num < 0):
>        break
>      if (num % 2 == 0):
>        total += 1
>    print total`